# VRX wamv position using ROS2

Tags: ros2, topic, gazebo-ignition, position

I need information about the instant position of the wamv (osrf/vrx).

Using ROS1 + Gazebo11 it works in general properly:

```
rostopic echo /gazebo/model_states/pose[17]
```

However, in ROS2 and Gazebo Garden I don't know how to read the current position. The elements of the `/wamv/pose` group return either fixed values or other than *"pose"* in the *"component inspector"* in GazeboSim.
How to read the position of the device correctly? BTW: GPS and IMU readout is working correctly.

Comment: I think it would be valuable to provide more detail in this question: there are acronyms here that many people may not be familiar with (VRX? WAMV?), and even if the acronyms are understood it seems like your question isn't really about these things: it's about getting the pose of a model in Gazebo, right?

Comment: VRX (Virtual RobotX) is the simulation environment and wamv is the name of the boat model. All together are available on github→osrf/vrx. Perhaps this is too specific  question, for a specific model, rather than general for the ROS2/Gazebo concept.

Comment: my recommendation was more that you edit the post to contain this material, so that people looking for questions to answer may be more able to respond to it. But yes, as you've said, this may be asking too narrow-focused a question (rather than digging into the specifics of Gazebo).